# Send python input through mosquitto

Tags: python, input, client, message, mosquitto

Here is the code I'm running for my client. It works pretty well, but it doesn't allow python inputs to be made. I considered making another .py-file for typing and sending messages, but I'm not sure how to *import* the established connection.

Is it somehow possible to enable a python *input chat* using mqtt?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("hello/world")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+"| "+ userdate + " said: "+str(msg.payload))

id = raw_input('username: ')

client = mqtt.Client(id)


client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect_async("192.168.0.24", 1883, 60)

# Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
# handles reconnecting.
# Other loop*() functions are available that give a threaded interface and a
# manual interface.
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Well of course it's possible. I would however look into doing this asynchronously.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: What *specifically* is your question? "Yes" it can be done. What are you not sure of?